# Build a variable comparing two other variables

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames :

```
Response <- read.csv(file = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robintux/Datasets4StackOverFlowQuestions/master/Response.csv")
conversionRates <- read.csv(file = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robintux/Datasets4StackOverFlowQuestions/master/conversionRates.csv")
```

Now, i need build a `Exchange` variable in `Response` data frame comparing the values in     `conversionRates$originCountry` and `Response$CompensationCurrency`, this is my primary idea

```
 Response$Exchange <- conversionRates$exchangeRate[conversionRates$originCountry %in% Response$CompensationCurrency ]
```

But i have a problem with the last line of code :

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Exchange, value = c(1, 1.195826, 0.01562,  : 
  replacement has 84 rows, data has 4131
```

I feel that the problem is the length of the variables that I am comparing.I read that I can do it with a `dplyr` function (`left_join`).But I want to complete the task only using the basic functions of R

Comment: I tried another possible solution idea using `match`, but I didn't get the desired results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
indx <- match(Response$CompensationCurrency, conversionRates$originCountry)
Response$Exchange <- conversionRates[indx, "exchangeRate"]
```

`merge` would also work if you set `all.x = TRUE`.